# working with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My question is related to ggplot2 in R (3.2.3). I have 4 datasets containing 2 columns and about 80,000-100,000 rows. I used the below code for creating a plot for one the datasets:

```
dataset1 <- read.table("file1.txt", header=T)
ggplot(data=dataset1, aes(dataset1$length))+ geom_histogram (binwidth =500)+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1001,15000,by=1000))
```

Here, length is the 2th column of my dataset, I would like to have the plot, with x-axis shows the length between 300-1200 with interval of 200 (300,500,700,900,1200) and length between 1201-1500 with interval of 1000. So, I used the above code for scale_x_continuous, but it didn't produce what I want. Could you please help me with the correct code for this plotting?

Here is a short sample of data:

```
case length
C1099757    300
C1099759    300
C1099761    300
C1099763    300
C1100993    301
C1100995    301
C1100997    301
C1100999    301
C1101377    302
C1101379    302
C1101919    303
C1101921    303
C1102979    304
C1102981    304
C1102983    304
C1103475    305
C1103477    305
C1104267    306
C1104269    306
```

In the original data file, it continues to 12000 in the similar way that I posted. In your opinion, is ggplot2 suitable for this plotting, if not please suggest the right one.

Also, I'm looking for a way to show the length distribution of all 4 datasets in one graph in order to easily compare them. I would be highly appreciated if you could please let me know how I can do that?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I provided an answer below. However, it would be easier if you would have provided sample data, e.g., using iris. Furthermore your intervals done match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should replace

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1001,15000,by=1000))
```

by

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1001,15000,by=1000)))
```

or

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(300,1000,by=200)+
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1001,15000,by=1000))
```

(wasn't entirely sure what you meant)

Based on your sample data i generated some artificial data which only contains length

```
 df1 = data.frame(length=runif(300,300,1200))
 df2 = data.frame(length=runif(300,300,1200))
 df3 = data.frame(length=runif(300,900,1200))
 df2 = data.frame(length=runif(300,300,12000))
 df4 = data.frame(length=runif(300,300,12000))

# plotting a single dataset
 ggplot(data=df4, aes(length))+ geom_histogram (binwidth =500)+
 +     scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1001,15000,by=1000)))
#combine the datframes
df = data.frame(df1$length,df2$length,df3$length,df4$length)
library(reshape)
melted <- melt(df)
ggplot(data=melted, aes(value))+aes(fill=variable)+ geom_histogram (binwidth =500)+
     scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1001,15000,by=1000)))
```

[image]

or

```
 ggplot(data=melted, aes(value))+aes(fill=variable)+ geom_histogram (binwidth =500,position="dodge")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1001,15000,by=1000)))
```

[image]

To have a slightly nicer X-Axis labelling I redistributed the labels a bit and turned them by 45 degrees

```
ggplot(data=melted, aes(value))+aes(fill=variable)+ geom_histogram (binwidth =500,position="dodge")+
     scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1100,15000,by=1000)))+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

And the chart witch adjusts the Bins accordingly. I actually like the different bar sizes.

```
ggplot(data=melted, aes(value))+
        aes(fill=variable)+ 
        geom_histogram(breaks=c(seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1100,15000,by=1000)),position="dodge")+

        scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1100,15000,by=1000)))+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I used your suggested modification, but the plot isn't interesting due to large data amount. I want to attach the picture, but don't know how should it in the comment section.

Comment: I just did two small updates to incorporate the 4 datasets problems.
You can not upload images as comment :(
Best upload it somewhere to the web and provide a link.However, the "intrestingness" is probably more an issue of your data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Actually, the first combined plot is  my desired. However, the x-axis labels (left side of plot) is messy that is due to a large amount of data. Could you please let me know how it can be clear? and sorry for the further and probably a basic question, I didn't exactly  understand what does mean "data.frame(length=runif(300,300,1200))". It will be great if I have your explanation on this, I'm really new in R.

Comment: The command data.frame(length=runif(300,300,1200)) generates some sample data (300 points between 300 and 1200) to have a slightly larger data set. 
I also added another version with turned labels. One more thin I realised is that the bin width is currently only in the labels and not in the Histograms. Added another version for that one.
I hope the collection of charts I provided allows you to construct your desired chart. (accepting the answer if so would be nice ;) )

Comment: Many thanks for being here. I accepted your answer. Just one thing, I defined dataset1 as dataset1 <- read.table("file1.txt", header=T), please kindly let me know how I can combine all 4 datasets? I tried something like what you wrote (df = data.frame(df1$length,df2$length,df3$length,df4$length)), but it gave en error. Again thanks for all your help

Comment: You just need to replace by 
`df = data.frame(dataset1$length,dataset2$length,dataset3$length,dataset4$length))`

Comment: Sorry, this is my first experience, so please be patient with me. Firstly, I wrote these codes: dataset1<-read.table("1.txt", header=T)  
dataset2<-read.table("2.txt", header=T)  
dataset3<-read.table("3.txt", header=T)  
dataset4<-read.table("4.txt", header=T) Then I wrote your previous code for data.frame, that gives the following error:

Error in data.frame(dataset1$length, dataset2$length, dataset3$length,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 69031, 83390, 144103, 71111
 In your prefessional view, what should I do in these condistions?

Comment: Your files have different row length. 
to generate melted you can use `melted <- rbind(cbind(set=rep("Dataset 1",nrow(df1)), df1),cbind(set=rep("Dataset 2",nrow(df2)), df2),cbind(set=rep("Dataset 3",nrow(df3)), df3),cbind(set=rep("Dataset 4",nrow(df4)), df4)) ` replacing df1..df4 dataset. And in the plot definition value by length

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm getting crazy, I tried for hours your command for generating melted, it gives the error "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names". The name of row entries in the first column in all dataset wasn't the same, I thought it may be problematic, so I used the code of cols <- intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2)) followed by rbind(df1[,cols], df2[,cols]) then melted <- melt(cols) and the rest command for ggplot, which the following error happened "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found". please help again

Comment: You should have two columns in your dataset (melted). The given ggplot statements expect `variable` and `value`. Most likely you can fix your problem using `names(melted) <- c('variable','value')`. Otherwise you can update the ggplot statement.

Comment: Thanks so much, I try it.

Comment: Hi CAFEBABE, after many efforts, I couldn't still produce the correct plot. I think the problem is related to combine data frames with different row number. When I used your command rbind(cbind(set=rep("Dataset 1",nrow(df1)), df1),cbind(set=rep("Dataset 2",nrow(df2)), df2),cbind(set=rep("Dataset 3",nrow(df3)), df3),cbind(set=rep("Dataset 4",nrow(df4)), df4)) for this comination and plotted a graph, just one variable (for dataset1) appeared, sounds that the combination didn't act here. Could you please suggest me another command to combine data frames with different row numbers? Many thanks

Comment: Dear friend, CAFEBABE, please advise me as before on this matter. I'm searching too much on the net but nothing was suitable.

Comment: Can you include the current statement for building melted at the end of the question and the result of `head(melted)` and also `tail(melted)`. Please also add the final plot command you have been using

Comment: Finally, I found the problem. It related to the format of melted, which have 3 coulmns as here, set contig length (header) 1 Dataset 1   seq1    773, so I added the "measure=c(3)) to the end of melt command, the head changed to set contig variable value (header) 1 Dataset 1   seq1   length   773. At the end, I plotted using this command: ggplot(data=melted, aes(value))+aes(fill=set)+ geom_histogram (binwidth =500)+
+scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(300,1000,by=200),seq(1001,15000,by=1000)))
The plot sounds well. sorry for such writing, it's hard to read. Again thanks for everything