# How to combine several dataframes with different rows using R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several text files containing **2 columns and different row numbers**. I would like to follow drawing a plot using ggplot2 as explained [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632751/working-with-ggplot2/34632827?noredirect=1#comment57035833_34632827); however, it works well for dataframes with equal row numbers, and I couldn't reproduce it with dataframes with different row numbers.
please let me know **how** **I should combine these data frames (dataframes with different row number) using R?**

```
case siza
case1 129
case2 129
case3 130 
case4 131
case5 132
case6 132
```

Thank you

Comment: I assume they're the same columns in each data frame, named the same? If so, just use `z <- rbind(x, y)` where x and y are your two data frames.

Comment: dataframe have the same columns but, the different row. For right plotting, they have to combined based on 2th coulmns (named for example "size"), could you please help me how I can do it for these dataframes? I used "df = data.frame(df1$size,df2$size) for dataframes with equal row number, but don't know for dataframes with different row number.

Comment: are you trying to (1) merge/bind the columns together, then (2) melt and plot them? If so you'll want to cbind the columns then plot them.

Comment: If you edit your question with some sample data, you will get a clearer answer.

Comment: Yes, I used df = data.frame(df1$size,df2$size), then melt and finally plotting for dataframes with the equal row number, but I have a problem with combining dataframes with different row numbers.

Comment: If you want to join dataframes together based on an index column (size) try `merge`. e.g. `x = merge(df1, df2, by="size")`, which works similar to SQL join. However, if you want to add the rows from df2 to the bottom of df1 `rbind` is probably your answer.

Comment: As an aside, I would probably do this with a list, to keep your code tidy:
`f = list.files("dir/dir", full.path=T)`
`x = lapply(f, function(i){read.csv(i)})`
`x = do.call("rbind.data.frame", x)` Anything else you might need to do to process files can be added after the `read.csv` command, to make it easier to read split the lapply function over separate lines.

Comment: I tried the merge and rbind command, but they weren't suitable. My mean from the combination is to put together the "size" column of various dataframes, which have different row number. please suggest me a right command.

Comment: If they have different number of rows, use the `all` argument in the `merge` function. As such: `merge(x, y, by = "size", all = TRUE)`. This will fill in the non-matched values with NAs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from the comments that you're actually trying to merge multiple columns and then plot each column individually. The problem, however, is that each of these columns has a different number of rows. Therefore you need to combine them based on some common variable (i.e. row names).

Using the examples from the link you provided:

```
df1 = data.frame(size=runif(300,300,1200))

#now adding an unequal column
df2 = data.frame(size=df1[c(1:275),])
```

Now merge the data frames based on row number. "all=TRUE" keeps all the values, "by=0" merges by row.names.

```
df.all=merge(df1$size,df2$size,by=0,all=TRUE)

#and to order the row names.
df.all=df.all[order(as.numeric(df.all[,1])),]

#finally if you want to remove the NA values
df.all[is.na(df.all)]=0
```

Does that get you the data.frame you want?